# Find the mass of a rod of length 2m with density $\delta$(x) = $\sqrt{2x}$ kg/m given at a distance of x m from the left end.

Tags: calculus

I have that mass is equal to $\int_0^2\delta(x)dx$, which when I substitute in the value for $\delta(x)$, I get $8/3$ kg, but the solutions for this problem show that the answer is $2\sqrt6$ kg. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your correct is correct for the linear density function $\delta(x)$ that was specified.

---

Write $\delta(x)=2^{1/2}x^{1/2}$ so that it is easier to apply the power rule in reverse when integrating:

$$m=\int_{0}^{2}{\delta(x)\,dx}=2^{1/2}\int_{0}^{2}{x^{1/2}\,dx}=2^{1/2}\left[\tfrac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\right]_{0}^{2}=2^{1/2}\times\tfrac{2}{3}\times(2^{3/2}-0)=\frac{8}{3}\text{ kg}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, there is some error in your calculation, $$\int_{0}^{2}\delta (x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt {2 x}\ dx=\sqrt 2\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt x\ dx=\sqrt 2\left[\frac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}\right]_{0}^{2}=\sqrt 2\left[\frac{2^{3/2}}{3/2}-0\right]=\frac{2\cdot 2\sqrt 2}{3}=\color{red}{\frac{8}{3} \ kg}$$

Comment: I apologize, it was the x was also supposed to be under the square root